# kartik yii2 mpdf - set header height

Tags: pdf, yii2, mpdf

I am using kartik mpdf in YII2. And I need to show the full header in every page. It may have a height of 450px.

[image]

Currently it's shown as above. How can I fix it?

Comment: show your  related  html code .. ( and css)

Answer (score 3):

**marginTop**: float, sets the page top margin for the new document (in millimetres).

You can use 'marginTop' => 119

Answer (score 1):

The margins can be set using the syntax below, for the top margin adjust the marginTop as required

```
new Pdf([
          'mode' => '', // leaner size using standard fonts
          'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
          'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
          'marginTop' => 0,
          'marginBottom' => 0,
          'marginLeft' => 0,
          'marginRight' => 0,
          'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
          'content' => $this->renderPartial('certificate_pdf', ['']),
          'options' => [
            // any mpdf options you wish to set
          ],
          'methods' => [
            'SetTitle' => '',
            'SetSubject' => '',
            'SetHeader' => [''],
            'SetFooter' => [''],
            'SetAuthor' => 'Ajira Tracking',
            'SetCreator' => 'Ajira Tracking',
            'SetKeywords' => 'Ajira Tracking',
          ]
        ]);
```